# Intersection of two hash-maps using clojure

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure. My question is that how to get a intersection of two hash-maps, e.g.

```
(def map-1 {"a" 2, "b" 1, "c" 4, "d" 3})
(def map-2 {"a" 3, "b" 6, "e" 5})
```

As we defined two maps, the expected result would be `{"a" 3, "b" 6}`, it is in a map with intersected keys and the max value of the key.

Somehow I came up with a solution and implemented it, but it works partially correct.

Basic idea is that find the map which has the smallest amount of items in it, use it as a reference. For each item in the reference map to check whether the other map contains it. If it contains, put the key to output map with its max value (using `(max num1 num2)`)

The following is my sample code:

```
(defn max-intersect [map1 map2]
  (let [smaller-map (if (< (count map1) (count map2))
                      map1
                      map2)
        longer-map (if (= smaller-map map1)
                     map2
                     map1)]
        (loop [output {}
               reference-map smaller-map]
          (if (empty? reference-map)
            output
            (recur (let [[item-key item-val] (first smaller-map)]
                     (when (contains? longer-map item-key)
                       (assoc output item-key (max item-val (get longer-map item-key)))))
                   (rest reference-map))))))
```

This is my repl result:

```
test-intersect.core=> (def map1 {"a" 2, "b" 1, "c" 4, "d" 3})
#'test-intersect.core/map1
test-intersect.core=> (def map2 {"a" 3, "b" 6, "e" 5})
#'test-intersect.core/map2
test-intersect.core=> (max-intersect map1 map2)
{"a" 3}
```

It may seem complex, I am also waiting for any great and efficient solutions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with [`merge-with`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge-with) using `max` as the merging function:

```
(def map-1 {"a" 2, "b" 1, "c" 4, "d" 3})
(def map-2 {"a" 3, "b" 6, "e" 5})
(merge-with max map-1 map-2)
=> {"a" 3, "b" 6, "c" 4, "d" 3, "e" 5}
```

`merge-with` is like `merge` but it allows you to pass a function to pick the merged value when a key appears in both maps.

To only include keys that appear in both maps, you could then use `select-keys` with the set intersection of both maps' keys:

```
(select-keys (merge-with max map-1 map-2)
             (clojure.set/intersection
               (set (keys map-1))
               (set (keys map-2))))
```

Comment: Thank you for illustrating the solution with explain! I think there are many built-in functions I don't know and need to study further. Is there any good studying resource you recommend? Thanks again!

Comment: Kamikid: solving 4clojure exercises, you will discover many new functions. Also take a look at the Clojure Cheatsheet.

Comment: @Kamikid what Michiel said, plus 1) skimming the [clojure.core API docs](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html) helps give a broad sense and 2) look up interesting functions on clojuredocs.org and at the bottom of each page there are _related_ functions which is another way to discover useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
(require '[clojure.set :refer [intersection]])

(defn merge-with-max-intersecting
  [m1 m2]
  (let [intersecting (intersection (set (keys m1))
                                   (set (keys m2)))]
    (merge-with max
                (select-keys m1 intersecting)
                (select-keys m2 intersecting))))

(merge-with-max-intersecting {"a" 2, "b" 1, "c" 4, "d" 3}
                             {"a" 3, "b" 6, "e" 5})
;;=> {"a" 3, "b" 6}
```

Comment: Thank you Michiel to implement your solution. It seems like merge-with is quite handy and useful when shaping collection with function.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it in one pass like this:

```
(defn merge-maps [m1 m2]
  (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v]
               (if (contains? m1 k)
                 (assoc acc k (max v (m1 k)))
                 acc))
             {}
             m2))

user> (merge-maps map-1 map-2)
;;=> {"a" 3, "b" 6}
```

Comment: Thank you for offering new way to solve the problem. This logic is straightforward to me and the solution is quite fancy!